# How do I add extra download directories to AppArmor for Firefox running under snap?

Tags: firefox, snap, freeze, downloads, apparmor

I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04.1 and went to a site where I occasionally download things from. I typically save files from this site to an sshfs mount shared from another system on my home network, which is outside of the `~/Download` path, but mounted as a subdirectory of my `$HOME`.

Firefox froze when I first tried downloading, and I eventually realized it was being blocked by AppArmor. When it happened a second time, I stopped the AppArmor service, and Firefox unfroze, but it still got a Permission Denied error.

Here are some example `dmesg` audit messages from the initial failure:

```
[Mon Dec 12 09:56:59 2022] audit: type=1400 audit(1670596598.697:172985): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/fstab" pid=1048673 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Mon Dec 12 09:57:00 2022] audit: type=1107 audit(1670596598.829:172986): pid=1076 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.32040" pid=1048673 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1366885 peer_label="unconfined"
[Mon Dec 12 09:57:00 2022] audit: type=1107 audit(1670596598.829:172988): pid=1076 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.32040" pid=1048673 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1366885 peer_label="unconfined"
[Mon Dec 12 09:57:08 2022] audit: type=1400 audit(1670596606.925:172990): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/mike/sshfs/filename.txt" pid=1048673 comm="firefox" requested_mask="wc" denied_mask="wc" fsuid=1000 ouid=1006
[Mon Dec 12 09:57:08 2022] audit: type=1400 audit(1670596606.925:172990): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/mike/sshfs/filename-1.txt" pid=1048673 comm="firefox" requested_mask="wc" denied_mask="wc" fsuid=1000 ouid=1006
[Mon Dec 12 09:57:08 2022] audit: type=1400 audit(1670596606.925:172990): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/mike/sshfs/filename-2.txt" pid=1048673 comm="firefox" requested_mask="wc" denied_mask="wc" fsuid=1000 ouid=1006
[...previous message repeats many times with an incrementing number on the filename...]
```

(Annoyingly, this failure ended up created a few tens of thousands of zero-length files)

After doing `systemctl stop apparmor`, the messages changed a bit, no longer repeating almost endlessly, but I get a pretty straight denial:

```
[Mon Dec 12 10:02:58 2022] audit: type=1400 audit(1670596957.682:187529): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/mike/sshfs/" pid=1366974 comm="pool-firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1006
[...snip some dbus-related messages...]
[Mon Dec 12 10:03:10 2022] audit: type=1400 audit(1670596969.158:187537): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/mike/sshfs/filename.txt.part" pid=1366974 comm=4261636B67726F7E506F6F6C202332 requested_mask="wc" denied_mask="wc" fsuid=1000 ouid=1006
[Mon Dec 12 10:03:10 2022] audit: type=1400 audit(1670596969.166:187538): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/mike/sshfs/filename.txt.part" pid=1366974 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=1006
```

How do I add extra directories for Firefox to have write permission? Would anything special need to be done for an sshfs path as opposed to something on the local filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I saw another answer here about granting permissions to an extra file/folder with AppArmor, so I believe this should also be applicable for you (but I'm not an expert on AppArmor rules).

Try the following:

- Add a local override to `/etc/apparamor.d/local/usr.bin.firefox`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.firefox
  ```
- Add this line for the directory you want access to:

  ```
  /home/mike/sshfs/ rw,
  ```

  (If you want more directories, you can add several lines.)
- Save and exit nano <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Reload AppArmor entries for Firefox:

  ```
  sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparamor.d/local/usr.bin.firefox
  ```
- And finally restart Firefox.

Hopefully this will allow access to the folder.